# Using charAt(index) in android

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to assign a String to different Buttons, such that each character in the String gets assigned to each Button using the String.charAt(index) method. Like:

```
private String myString = "34567124";
/*Getting the Views*/
Button bUtton1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button bUtton2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
Button bUtton3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
//...Rest of the Buttons

/*Setting text for each View*/
bUtton1.setText(myString.charAt(0));
bUtton2.setText(myString.charAt(1));
bUtton3.setText(myString.charAt(2));
...//Rest of the Buttons
```

Why is this leading to an error?

Comment: Try converting the char to a String (String.valueOf(myString.charAt(0))) not completely sure.

Comment: What is the error message - please edit the question and include the error log.

Comment: because `charAt` returns a `char`, and `setText(char)` is not a method that exists.

Comment: `String.valueOf(myString.charAt(index))` works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you might consider splitting `myString` (this will convert it into an array of single-character strings). Then you can do something like this:

```
private String myString = "34567124";
//here I am splitting...
private String[] digitsArray = myString.split("");
...
//then you can do this:
bUtton1.setText(digitsArray[0]);
bUtton2.setText(digitsArray[1]);
bUtton3.setText(digitsArray[2]);
```

Give it a try and let me know if this does what you intended.

Comment: The method charAt(index) does not exist for a String[ ] stringArray

Comment: But I don't use that method anywhere in my code? Did I miss something?

Comment: Cool, please vote/accept the answer so you question can be marked as answered. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Buttons have no `setText` method that accepts a `char`.
Because it gets treated like a resource ID.
It does accept a `String` or any implementations of `CharSequence`.

Instead of `charAt`, you can use [substring](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)):

```
    String myString = "12345678";
    btn.setText(myString.substring(0, 1));
    btn.setText(myString.substring(1, 2));
    btn.setText(myString.substring(2, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple change will resolve your error:

```
private String myString = "34567124"; 
/*Getting the Views*/ 
Button bUtton1 =     (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); 
Button bUtton2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2); 
Button bUtton3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3); 
//...Rest of the Buttons 
/*Setting text for each View*/ 
bUtton1.setText(""+myString.charAt(0)); 
bUtton2.setText(""+myString.charAt(1));     
bUtton3.setText(""+myString.charAt(2)); 
...//Rest of the Buttons
```

> Adding a preceding concatenation will resolve the error as the setText method recieves String as an argument.

Comment: String.valueOf(myString.charAt(index)) works perfectly

Comment: `charAt()` returns a char, and `setText(char)` is not a method that exists.

Comment: I think adding a preceding concatenation to the `char` still can work

Comment: String.valueOf will also work. My solution is based on Java concept called automatic up casting. If a string is concatenated with any object, it gets upcasted to string automatically.